# Handling JSON POST request using PHP and SHA1

Tags: php, ruby, json, post, sha1

So I am using a REST API, where the API issues a POST request to my server in JSON format. Following is the information it sends:

```
info: {
id: "9890dsds8",
number: 5,
amount: 33
},
sig: "8jhjbhb78979899h"
```

sig is a SHA1 signature of the info, this should be used to validate the post. For example, we can validate the info in Ruby with (as given in their example):

```
require 'json'
require 'cgi'
require 'digest/sha1'

key = "some_key"
params = CGI::parse(post_body)
digest = Digest::SHA1.hexdigest(params["info"]+key)

if digest == params["sig"]
# Valid signature
info = JSON.parse(params["info"])
# Respond with status code 200 and some unique_id
else
# Invalid signature. You should response with a non-200 response code.
end
```

The unique_id must be a string of UTF8 characters 50 characters in length or less and should be the only contents of the body of your response.

Though I am quite able to understand what's happening, I am not completely able to figure out everything. Mostly, may be because its in Ruby.

Can someone please help me on how to do this in PHP? I am not able to handle this JSON POST request in PHP. A PHP converted version of the snippet would be extremely appreciated. I am also not sure, how to deal with SHA1 aspects in PHP, any special knowledge required?

Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 2):

I assume that the API will populate the "response" variable in your POST array.

Then:

```
//Get the JSON string
$json_string = $_POST['response'];

//Decode JSON string to array
$decoded = json_decode($json_string);

//Calculate SHA1 (I am not sure how ruby is concatenating a string with an array, so I will just convert the array to string using implode).
$key = 'somekey';
$hash = sha1(implode("",$decoded['info']) . $key);

if($hash == $decoded['sig']){
 //OK!
}else{
 //Not OK!
}
```